# Verify the content of azure devops feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, feed

I published a python package on azure dev ops feed i created in in azure devops artifacts.

It is possible to view what got uploaded in the feed in azure devops portal.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to view what got uploaded in the feed in azure devops portal.

I am afraid there is no such method to view specific files of the package directly in azure devops.

When you upload the package to Azure Feed, you need to run the command: `python setup.py sdist`.

In this case, the files will be packaged into `xxx.tar.gz` file.

In the package of azure feed, we can only see the name of the compressed package, but cannot directly view the specific file.

[image]

If you need to view the specific files, you need to run `pip install` to install the package. Then you could get the detailed files.

[image]

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

You could add your request for this feature on [our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions.